# How can I update a numpy array with index in another numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have

- an numpy.array **a** of shape (n1, n2, n3, n4)
- an index array **idx** of shape (n1, n2, i1)

what I want to do is like the code below

```
for i in range(n1):
    for j in range(n2):
        for k in range(i1):
            b[i, j, k, :] = a[i, j, idx[i, j, k], :]
```

if there is a numpy function to achieve this without for loop?

Comment: can you provide a short example? Also define `b`

Answer (score 0):

Using as starting point:

```
import numpy as np

n1, n2, n3, n4, i1 = range(2, 7)

a = np.random.randint(10, size=(n1, n2, n3, n4))
idx = np.random.randint(n3, size=(n1, n2, i1))
b = np.zeros_like(a, shape=(n1, n2, i1, n4))
```

In general you can do the following:

```
I, J, K = np.ogrid[:n1, :n2, :i1]
b[I, J, K] = a[I, J, idx]
```

Here the `I` `J` and `K` arrays are the equivalent of the loop variables `i` `j` and `k`. Their shapes have to be in agreement with the shape of `idx`.

In case `b` has shape (n1, n2, i1, n4) then you might as well do:

```
I, J, _ = np.ogrid[:n1, :n2, :1]
b = a[I, J, idx]
```

Or alternatively without `ogrid`:

```
b = np.take_along_axis(a, idx[...,np.newaxis], axis=2)
```

Here `newaxis` is used to insert a length-1 axis to allow broadcasting. Check out the [numpy indexing docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html) for more info.